# when deploying canary, how can I divide the existing version and the canary version...?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am making a pipeline that automates canary deployment using spinnaker's kayenta. When deploying canary, I want to deploy using helm chart, how can I divide the existing version and the canary version?

I want to insert a custom value while installing the canary version as a helm chart. How can I make this possible?

Comment: did you try something ?

Answer (score 0):

One existing version will be already running over the server.

When the **spinnaker** updating the build it will apply the latest helm chart YAML files to K8s cluster.

you can set the custom values into the **helm** using the `--set` and overwrite the `valus.yaml` pre-define values.

now suppose you are running istio inside the K8s cluster

you can apply the updated **weight** for the canary deployment.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: helloworld
spec:
  hosts:
    - helloworld
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: helloworld
        subset: v1
      weight: 90
    - destination:
        host: helloworld
        subset: v2
      weight: 10
```

in the above example YAML you can change the **weight** & **lables** as per need.